# PowerShell Error handling using Try Catch block resulting wrong result

Tags: powershell

I have two services one of the service name is wrong (Spooler1). When I run the Invoke-command to stop the service using try catch block it is resulting wrong message.

Example:

```
[array]$Services = "spooler1","spooler"
$ComputerName = 'localhost'
For ($i=0; $i -lt $Services.Count; $i++)
{
    Try
        {
            #Stop service
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {param($Service) Stop-Service $Service} -ArgumentList $Services[$i]
            Write-Host "Try Block"
        }
    Catch
        {
            Write-Host "Catch Block"

        }
}
```

Result:

```
Cannot find any service with service name 'spooler1'.
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (spooler1:String) [Stop-Service], ServiceCommandException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopServiceCommand
+ PSComputerName        : localhost

Try Block
Try Block
```

When I run above Powershell Script it is resulting message 'Try Block' for both the services.

But the result should be

```
Catch Block
Try Block
```

Do we have any workaround to fix this issue.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600921/handle-errors-in-scriptblock-in-invoke-command-cmdlet

Answer (score 3):

After adding ErrorAction stop at the end of the Invoke-command statement it is handling error correctly.

```
..
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {param($Service) Stop-Service $Service} -ArgumentList $Services[$i] -ErrorAction Stop
```

Result:

```
Catch Block
Try Block
```

Answer (score 1):

`Invoke-Command` is returning a *non-terminating* error when it cannot find the first service, which does **not** trigger the `catch{}` block.

As you have discovered, by explicitly specifying `-ErrorAction Stop` this causes the error from the cmdlet to be handled as a terminating error and therefore trigger the `catch{}`.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/09/16/understanding-non-terminating-errors-in-powershell/